# config.json how to define the network?

Tags: node, config

I want to run several nodes on one machine. How can i define the network (`mainnet`, `alphanet`, `zeronet`) in the `config.json`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to set the *network* in the `config.json` file.

The *network* is somehow hard-coded on each branch (`mainnet`,`alphanet`,`zeronet`) as each network comes with its specific constants and a genesis block (which basically defines the network identifier).
The `config.json` file aims to configure the behavior of a node (rpc port, number of connections, history mode, …) regardless of the network it interacts with.

Comment: Could you point me to a source, how to realize, what i want to do? My problem is, i've an compiled mainnet node and everytime i want to start the alphanet node (cd into the alphanet dir) it starts to sync the mainnet instead the alphanet.

Comment: First, To run on different networks, you have to run different binaries. (This is not the same `tezos-node` that is produced by make in the git branch "alphanet" and "mainnet" of the gitlab repo.) So to run an alphanet node, you have to checkout and compile binaries from the alphanet branch.
Second, "bootstrap peers" the peers you first connect to when you launch a node aren't the same on mainnet and alphanet of course, so if you specify by hand bootstrap peers in your config.json, you mustn' use the same config.json to launch "alphanet"-tezos-node and "mainnet"-tezos-node...

Comment: I personally use a git feature called `worktree`. It allows you to checkout a branch in a given directory. You will have one folder for each branch you want. Then, you just need to pull/make/run in each directory. If you want to run several nodes on the same machine, do not forget to specify different ports, for both p2p and rpc `listen_addr`, and `data-dir`.

Comment: I've done a checkout and compiled the alphanet and mainnet branch, i also haven't set any bootstrap peers for both. Both branches are in different folders. But i don't get why ./tezos-node run (in the alphanet dir) starts to sync the mainnet. Maybe the listen_addr is the problem... will try it and give feedback. thx guys.

Comment: @vect0r helped me to find the problem. `git branch`gave me `*alphanet`but `git log`pointed to the `mainnet` branch. 

`git reset --hard origin/alphanet`and `make`solved the problem.